# Just a basic clicker but keep getting error

Tags: excel, vba

Not sure what I am doing wrong here.
Couple things to keep in mind.

1. Cells B7 and B8 are merged.
2. The code is started by a VB button
3. This is a protected sheet however the cells in question are not protected. When I run the script I get this error:

   Run-time error '1004':
   Application-defined or object-defined error

```
        Sub OneClickLetterSend()
    With Worksheets("Menu").Range("B7")
        Select Case .Value
            Case 802
                .Value = .Value + 1
                Range("B7").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
            Case 803
                .Value = .Value + 1
                Range("B7").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            Case 804
                .Value = .Value - 2
                Range("B7").Interior.Color = RGB(180, 0, 255)
            Case Else
        End Select
    End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: Side note... change all the lines beginning with `Range("B7").Interior...` to just `.Interior...` That way they refer back to the `With Worksheets("Menu").Range("B7")`.

Comment: Range("B7").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255) is throwing the error

Comment: Get rid of the `Range("B7")`. That line is currently referring to the `ActiveSheet`, not necessarily `Worksheets("Menu")`.

Comment: Done but still throwing the error.

Comment: The more research I do, the more I think this is an Excel issue than a coding issue.

Comment: I did double check, the cells are not protected and it only happens when the sheet is protected.

Comment: Have you ticked to allow "Format cells" when protecting the worksheet? even if the cell is not locked, that only seems to affect data

Comment: Never mind, you were right Edoardo. Thats exactly what it was

Comment: Edoardo if you want to throw an answer up I will upvote it and delete mine.

Comment: Looks like there’s already an answer mentioning “Format cells” by the time I rechecked, you can accept that one if you want, glad the problem was found

Comment: No you deserve the credit. You solved the problem.

Comment: I appreciate the offer, but it’s a valid answer and I would not add anything meaningful with another, I don’t mind for this question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Protect Sheet feat. Format Cells

- If you haven't already, unlock cell `B7` and under
  `Allow all users of this worksheet to:`
  tick `Format cells`.
- If for any reason that is not possible, play with the out-commented `Unprotect` and `Protect` lines in the code.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub OneClickLetterSend()
    With Worksheets("Menu").Range("B7")
        '.Worksheet.Unprotect
        Select Case .Value
            Case 802
                .Value = .Value + 1
                .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255) ' Blue
            Case 803
                .Value = .Value + 1
                .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) ' Green
            Case 804
                .Value = .Value - 2
                .Interior.Color = RGB(180, 0, 255)
            Case Else
        End Select
        '.Worksheet.Protect
    End With
End Sub
```